# How to make two list of tables?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing abook about **Matlab** and I do want to have two lists of tables; one of them for  tables which are related to `.m` files and the other one list of tables which are related to other subjects. How can I do make these two lists of tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `float` or `caption` package to define two different type of floats.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{mtable}[M Table][List of M Tables]
\begin{document}

\listoftables
\listofmtables

\begin{table}[ht]
foo
\caption{Foo A}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
foo
\caption{Foo B}
\end{table}

\begin{mtable}[ht]
bar
\caption{Bar A}
\end{mtable}
\begin{mtable}[ht]
bar
\caption{Bar B}
\end{mtable}

\end{document}
```